# Asp.net determining SSL cert expiration of IIS site

Tags: asp.net, ssl, certificate

I am trying to use Net.WebRequest and Net.WebResponse to connect to a site and get the expiration date for an SSL certificate. I look through all the properties of both the request and response and can't find this information. Can anyone help?

```
    ' Initialize the WebRequest. 
    Dim myRequest As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("https://testsite.com")

    ' Return the response.  
    Dim myResponse As Net.WebResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()
```

Is there a way to use the servicepoint of the WebRequest for this?